# Specify "Excel Only" in the manifest file

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I submitted an Excel add-in several days ago. Today, I received a change requirement:

> 1.2 Your app or add-in must work according to your description, and must not be in an unfinished state.`
>
> Your add-in claims to work in the Word, PowerPoint and Project clients however it does not appear to be fully functional as there appears to be no interaction between your add-in and the mentioned clients, except for the Excel client. Please ensure your add-in works in all declared applications.
> If you do not intent to support the Word, PowerPoint and Project clients, please make the relevant changes in your add-in manifest.

I don't know where (in the manifest file) to specify this add-in is for **Excel only**. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your manifest, there will be a section like:

```
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
    <Host Name="Project" />
    <Host Name="Document" />
</Hosts>
```

Remove all the `<Host ... />` lines except the one containing "Workbook", and you'll be all set.

See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests for more information.

Comment: In this version, I don't plan to enable add-in commands. So I don't need to have  `<VersionOverrides ...>...</VersionOverrides>`, right? Otherwise, elements such as `Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon` should be provided by myself? If it is an image, how come its extention is `Icon`?

Comment: Correct, if you're not doing app commands you can stick to the simplified V1 version, and just replace the hosts list there.

Comment: From 1st July, all the Excel add-ins must have add-in commands. But I really don't know if I should provide those numerous `resid` or just keep them as in the sample...

Comment: @SoftTimur, I don't think the statement that "From 1st July, all the Excel add-ins must have add-in commands" is correct.  It's true that add-ins must start using the 1.1 manifest format, but the add-in commands block (the `VersionOverrides` block) is optional.

Comment: I received a change request on the 8th July for an add-in, because I didn't implement add-in commands. It seems that it is mandatory, here is [a screenshot](http://www.filedropper.com/screenshot2016-08-26at024645).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot, looks like we have a disconnect here between documentation, actual policy, and enforced policy.  I'll follow up on this from my end.  For your particular submission, maybe wait a week, and then try submitting again, referencing this thread.

Comment: Sure... Following this change request, I just added add-in commands, and it worked. FYI, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38618005/702977) was the most tedious one, the support took several weeks to fix it, hope it will not reproduce when i submit another add-in. So now, I have 3 addins available in the store, but I am going to unpublish and republish them very soon due to the change of my statut.

Comment: For the other thread, did you figure out what had prevented the correct categorization? Please feel free to post an update on that other thread, in case someone experiences a similar issue...

Comment: In the end, the support wrote to me: `this issue was something in our end here that has been fixed now. As per Engineers report, they said that our process has already been updated such that this should not be an issue in the future.` I guess it was because I modified the add-ins several times following several change requests (due to lack of experience), which produced some complex cases for the system. We will see if that reproduces...