# Make an add-in available in Excel 2016 for Windows

Tags: ms-office, office-js

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437781/javascript-api-does-not-work-for-excel-2013), I have modified the manifest file of my two add-ins, and resubmitted to the store. Yesterday, I got a mail to say one is approved, and today I got another mail to say the other one is approved as well.

However, I could not find them in `Excel 2016 for Windows`. Then I go to the web page of the [Office Store](https://store.office.com/search.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&clickedfilter=OfficeProductFilter%3AExcel&productgroup=Excel). I could find the two add-ins, but I see in their page: `This add-in requires one of the following applications: Excel 2016 for Mac`, that's it, it does NOT mention `Excel 2016 for Windows`. (I have not checked them in Excel 2016 for Mac, because I have not installed Excel 2016 for Mac).

The follows is the part related to version in their manifest file. So does anyone know how to modify this to make the add-in available in `Excel 2016 for Windows`, where my add-ins work fine.

Moreover, once I modify their manifest, I should unpublish the add-ins, and then re-submit them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.2"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="...Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
```

Comment: Could you link to your add-in?

Comment: [Formula Formatter](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380385&sourcecorrid=b1272264-1d5a-4d8a-b1b3-804a0398e0d8&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false) and [Bottleneck Detector](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380386&sourcecorrid=29b9fd79-2127-4c9f-ba9d-c5ca35247977&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false)

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest is correct for enabling an add-in in Excel 2016 for Windows, Mac, and Excel Online.

It's possible that the validation team manually tagged your add-in to not support Excel 2016 for one of the following reasons:

- You specified in the description or the "Testing Notes" field that the add-in shouldn't be supported on Excel 2016 for Windows.
- The validators found a bug that was specific to Windows. Normally if that happened they would reject your submission at least once first and include an explanation in the report. So check all your previous submission reports for information.

If none of the above are the reason, then there was some other problem during validation, perhaps a bug. On your Seller Dashboard page:

1. Scroll to the bottom and click `Support`:[image]
2. Problem type: App submission and validation
3. Category: App validation results
4. Start email (the team with expertise here is in Europe, so the chat/call is likely to be unsuccessful during North American business hours)[image]
5. Describe the issue briefly/politely, including links to your add-ins, and submit

Comment: OK... I will contact them and update this thread. Additionally, I am still struggling with this [UserVoice Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492961/embed-a-uservoice-widget-in-an-add-in-in-excel-for-windows). I wanted to do this because I saw the widget in your stock connector, didn't you have trouble when you implemented it? Thank you...